# How to resolve git SSH issues on windows, ssh key generated and added, authenticates but still can't clone or push

Tags: git, github

I've been trying to setup git on my windows machine, while I've done this many times in the past on various OS's I'm getting a strange issue this time around. Nothing seems to work, and it's getting extremely frustrating so I've finally resorted to posting here.

What I've tried:

1. I generated a key pair using `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"`
2. I added the key to my ssh agent using `ssh-add`
3. I added the public key to my account on github.com both manually and using the github cli on my second attempt when things weren't working
4. ran `ssh -T git@github.com` to verify and got `> Hi USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.` back, as expected
5. tried to clone a repository (using ssh), got
   `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`
6. Tried redoing various steps 1 -4 with no success.
7. made a new SSH key specifically for github
8. added it to the ssh agent, and github, and tried again. no luck
9. deleted my known hosts and ssh config files to see if something in there was messing it up, still no luck.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake: do you have access to the repo you're trying to clone?

Comment: yep, it's my repository.